# Property of Observable is Empty

Tags: angular, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2, observable

I've worked through most of the Heroes tutorial and have decided to add a Hero Tracker which displays a map with the Hero's location on it.

This worked when the values were mocked up in a constant but now I'm calling a rest service and the Location property is empty.  I'm sure I just have this written poorly and could use some help with the syntax.

Here is the hero map component:

```
import 'rxjs/add/operator/switchMap';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { Component, OnInit, NgZone } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute, Router, ParamMap } from '@angular/router';

import { Hero, HeroService } from '../heroes/hero.service';
import { HeroLocationService } from './hero-location.service';
import { HeroLocation } from './hero-location';

@Component({
    template: `
    <style>
        agm-map {
          height: 300px;
          width: 400px;
        }
    </style>
    <h2>HERO MAP</h2>
      <div *ngIf="hero$ | async as hero">
        <h3>{{ hero.HeroName }}'s location is {{ hero.Location }}</h3>
            <div *ngIf="loc$ | async as loc">
                <h4>Latitude: {{ loc.lat() }} Longitude: {{ loc.lng() }}</h4>
                <agm-map [latitude]="loc.lat()" [longitude]="loc.lng()">
                    <agm-marker [latitude]="loc.lat()" [longitude]="loc.lng()"></agm-marker>
                </agm-map>
            </div>
        <p>
          <button (click)="gotoHeroes(hero)">Back</button>
        </p>
      </div>
  `
})
export class HeroMapComponent implements OnInit {
    hero$: Observable<Hero>;
    loc$: Observable<any>;

  constructor(
    private service: HeroService,
    private router: Router,
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
    private locationservice: HeroLocationService
  ) {}

  ngOnInit() {

      var hloc: string;

      //the problem is here //////////////////////////////////////
      this.hero$ = this.route.paramMap
          .switchMap((params: ParamMap) =>              
              this.service.getHero(params.get('id')));  

      this.hero$.subscribe(function (z) {
          hloc = z.Location.toString();
      });
      ////////////////////////////////////////////////

      this.loc$ = this.locationservice.getGeocoding(hloc);
  }

  gotoHeroes(hero: Hero) {
      let heroId = hero ? hero.Id : null;

      // Pass along the hero id if available
      // so that the HeroList component can select that hero.
      // Include a junk 'foo' property for fun.

      this.router.navigate(['/hero-tracker', { id: heroId, foo: 'foo' }]);
  }
}
```

I can see in Chrome's Network tab that data is being returned properly:

```
{"Id":11,"HeroName":"Batman","Location":"Chicago, Illinois"}
```

The hero.service looks like this:

```
import 'rxjs/add/observable/of';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Rx';

import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

export class Hero {
  constructor(public Id: number, public HeroName: string, public Location: string) { }
}

@Injectable()
export class HeroService {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  getHeroes(): Observable<Hero[]> {
      return this.http.get<Hero[]>('http://localhost:50125/api/heroes')
          .catch(error => Observable.throw(error));
  }

  getHero(id: number | string): Observable<Hero> {
      return this.http.get<Hero>('http://localhost:50125/api/heroes/' + id)
          .catch(error => Observable.throw(error));
  }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe your issue is trying to use location before it is actually back from the server.

try this:

```
      this.hero$.subscribe(z => {
          hloc = z.Location.toString();
          this.loc$ = this.locationservice.getGeocoding(hloc);
      });
```

hloc is set in the callback but is used outside of the subscribe which is an async operation. By using it only when hloc is set you can ensure it will have the same value as the server returned.

Comment: @TrevorBrooks Glad to help. If this answers your question sufficiently please accept it to aid others in the future.

Comment: Done!  Thanks again!